# 'runway error' for references

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

I am trying to reference in IEEE style and I have added the following commands to achieve so:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

and I have also imported `\usepackage{cite}`

but now the refences do not appear and at the end of every oaragraph with a reference is says 'runway error?'

what shall I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does wiping out all aux files (ilncluding the .blg and .bbl files) and recompiling from scratch -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- help? If not, does replacing `\bibliography{references.bib}` with `\bibliography{references}` and/or replacing `\usepackage{cite}` with `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}` help?

Comment: How do I wipe out the aux files?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: @MichaelAdlerstein - Overleaf-specific questions should be addressed to the Overleaf Helpdesk. Their support staff are top notch.